# How to reference files belonging to a module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, module

I am making a module that need to use some files, local to the module.

The path to the module can vary, depending on the level of nesting and depending on whether if its installed globally or locally.

How do I reference the modules local files from within the module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this to be the best solution:

**For javascript libraries:**

If its a javascript you want to include, you can add the relative path to a require call:

```
require('my-module/lib/other-script.js');
```

**For other files to open:**

Use the **module.filename** to obtain the absolute path to the current file. Remove the file name and add relative path name to it:

```
fileName = module.filename.substring(0,module.filename.lastIndexOf("/"))+"/my/local/file.txt";
```